# Determine the conditions for Brownian motion to be a Martingale

Tags: brownian-motion, martingale

Let $W_T$ denote normalised univariate Brownian motion and let

$X_t = W_t^2 + \alpha W_t + \beta t + \gamma$

where $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ are constants. Determine conditions on these constants such that $X_t$ is a Martingale.

Comment: you can use ito's lemma or compute the conditional expectation directly.

Comment: @Gordon. Thanks. Please could you expand on this a little? I'm completely new to this.

Comment: @Gordon is it simply just determining for which values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ the $dt$ term is equal to zero?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @Gordon isn't that true for any values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ as the second derivative $dt$ are zero for all terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Let $s<t$.
$$E[W_t^2|F_s]=E[(W_t-W_s)^2|F_s]+2 E[(W_t-W_s)W_s|F_s]+E[W_s^2|F_s]$$
so
$$E[W_t^2|F_s]=E[(W_t-W_s)^2]+2W_s E[(W_t-W_s)]+W_s^2=t-s+W_s^2$$

Also

$$E[\alpha  W_t|F_s]=\alpha  E[W_t-W_s|F_s]+\alpha E[ W_s|F_s]=\alpha  E[W_t-W_s]+\alpha  W_s=\alpha  W_s$$

and

$$E[\beta t+\gamma |F_s]=\beta t +\gamma$$

Comment: $\beta=-1$ and $\alpha , \gamma $  are arbitary

Comment: Thanks @math. I'm not sure I completely follow this argument so please can you explain a little more? I follow the maths I'm just not sure why, for instance, $t-s+W_s^2$ means that term is a Martingale in that form.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: $X_t= W_t^2+\alpha W_t- t +\gamma $ is a martingale for every $\alpha$ and $\gamma$

Comment: How do you know that is a Martingale?

Comment: $ E[ X_t | F_s]= X_s$

Comment: Just so I have it clear in my head: $E[X_t|F_s]= t - s + W_s^2 + \alpha W_s + \beta t + \gamma = W_s^2 + \alpha W_s - s + \gamma = X_s$ when $\beta = -1$